# Setting the size of a GTKEventBox

Tags: c++, gtk

I've got a `GtkHBox` with 2 items. Inside that, on the left, I have a `GtkHBox` with 4 items. The first two are `GtkEventBox`'s, followed by a `GtkHScale` and finally a `GtkLabel`.

The two `GtkEventBox`'s each contain a `GtkVBox` with two items, an image and a label (using the `GtkEventBox` so that I can catch click events on the image). Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to set the width for them. Currently, it looks like this:

[image: current_look]

But I want the Select and Pan sections to be much narrower. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to pack the event boxes into your `GtkHBox` with the `expand` and `fill` parameters set to false.

Comment: I could have *sworn* that I tried that, but it works now! Thanks!